# Vim custom command to execute 'c""<Esc>P'

Tags: vimscript, command

I am trying to write a custom command that executes the following: `'c""<Esc>P'`, namely cut visually selected text, insert `""`and paste the cut text into the quotes.

I have tried the following:

```
command! -range Wq <line1>,<line2> execute 'c""<Esc>P'
```

and some other variations of it, but none seem to work. How can I write a custom command to execute this command?

I know about [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) but would like to write my own functions instead of some plugins.

(Also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820541/vim-custom-command-to-execute-cescp, got recommended to also post on [vi SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
xnoremap Wq c""<Esc>P
```

Comment: Thanks! Also answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820541/vim-custom-command-to-execute-cescp with `xnoremap <key> c"<C-r>""<C-c>`.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of why the command/Ex version is wrong. (And yea, I prefer `xnoremap`, too.)